# Seems like it should be easy: Landscape Scrolling Text Field

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a application that I am working on that is in landscape mode and does not rotate. However I can not get the text field to rotate. I have been putting in way to many hours so don't be to harsh if this is a easy answer...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Interface Builder to create the view? In that case, adding the UITextField to the UIView in landscape mode. In case you do not know how to use IB for creating views in landscape mode, open the UIView object in IB. There is a small arrow on the top-right corner of the view. Click on that arrow to rotate the view to landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still think that it might be something as simple as that, but unfortunately that did not work. Its a new day so I will keep going!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Info.plist file so that it includes the "Initial device orientation" key and specify UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft (the Home button should be to the right if an app opens in landscape, according to Apple's UI guidelines). Some samples come with this property already in the plist, but most don't.